# Retrieving content of hyperlinked slides in powerpoint files(.PPTX) through apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to get the text content of powerpoint files and replace with some other text. I have a powerpoint file of 20 slides. where 13,14,15,16 slides have hyperlink to 17,18,19 and 20th slide. I am using XMLSlideshow to traverse through the slides, But it gives only 16 slides. It does not give last 4 hyperlinked slides.

Any idea really appreaciable in advance how can I get content of all hyperlinked slides and Replace by some other text.

here is my code.

public static void replaceContentInPPTX(File inputFile, File outputFile) throws IOException{

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    XMLSlideShow ppt = null;

    try{

        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ppt = new XMLSlideShow(fis);

        //  System.out.println("Available slide layouts:"+ppt.getSlideMasters().length);

        /*  for(XSLFSlideMaster master : ppt.getSlideMasters()){

            XSLFShape[] shape = master.getShapes();

            for(XSLFSlideLayout layout : master.getSlideLayouts()){

                System.out.println(layout.getType());

            }

        }*/

        System.out.println("No of slides:"+ppt.getSlides().length); // gives 16 slides.

        for(XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {

for(XSLFShape shape : slide){

                if(shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {

                    XSLFTextShape txShape = (XSLFTextShape)shape;


                    for (XSLFTextParagraph xslfParagraph : txShape.getTextParagraphs()) {

                        String originalText = replaceUnwantedChar(xslfParagraph.getText());

                        if(! originalText.isEmpty()) {

                            String translation = "";

                            if(translation != null ) {


                                CTRegularTextRun[] ctRegularTextRun = xslfParagraph.getXmlObject().getRArray();

                                for(int index = ctRegularTextRun.length-1; index > 0 ; index--){

xslfParagraph.getXmlObject().removeR(index);
                                }
                                ctRegularTextRun[0].setT(translation);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ppt.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        fis.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, did you try upgrading?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I am using latest version poi-3.10-beta2.jar, poi-ooxml-3.10-beta2.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-beta2.jar. All are latest version.